# Convert UTC Date to dd/mm/yyyy Format

Tags: javascript, date

I am having some difficulties when trying to convert UTC Date format to dd/mm/yyyy in JavaScript:

```
var launchDate = attributes["launch_date"];
if (isBuffering) {
         var date = new Date(launchDate);
         var d = new Date(date.toLocaleDateString());
         launchDate = ((d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCDate() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCFullYear()));
 }
```

I tried with this, but it returns me an invalid date. So I changed to this:

```
var launchDate = attributes["launch_date"];
if (isBuffering) {
         var date = new Date(launchDate);
         var d = formatDate(new Date(date.toLocaleDateString()));
         launchDate = ((d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCDate() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCFullYear()));
 }
```

However, it still returning me invalid Date. I wonder is there any possible way to change the date format of Fri May 31 2013 17:41:01 GMT+0200 (CEST) to dd/mm/yyyy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are only so many date formats Javascript natively recognizes. If you need a specific format that's not among those, you may have to engage in some custom object(s) that do the "in house" conversion to/from the formats you need to one that Javascript recognizes natively. Have gone down this road before, can be surprisingly tricky and land-mine prone :)

Answer (score 11):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

This will be more superior in build JS method!

Answer (score 7):

```
function formatDate(d)
 {
  date = new Date(d)
  var dd = date.getDate(); 
  var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear(); 
  if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
  if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm};
  return d = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy
}
```

Comment: But isn't getDate() getting current date? or is it getting the date of parameters passed in?

Comment: It does not work for same date, let's say 3/27/2008. But it works for 5/26/2008.

Comment: @radia How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Month is 0 indexed, but day is not. You don't need to add 1 to your day.

Also, you're formatting it for MM/dd/yyyy, not dd/MM/yyyy.

solution:

```js
    var launchDate = attributes["launch_date"];
    if (isBuffering) {
             var date = new Date(launchDate);
             var d = formatDate(new Date(date.toLocaleDateString()));
             launchDate = ((d.getUTCDate())+ "/" + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) +  "/" + (d.getUTCFullYear()));
     }
```

Comment: Eventhough I switch the date and month, it still returning invalid date

Comment: What line is it returning "invalid date"? can you use a debugger to tell us where it says that? It could be possible that your launchdate is formatted incorrectly to be parsed by new Date().

Comment: I used a debugger for browser and it just tells me that it is invalid date but there is value passing in, just that somehow the toLocaleDateString() causing error.

Comment: Step through the code using a breakpoint (red orb in IE, grey arrow in Chrome) and mouse over launchdate and date to see if it process it fine. I think new Date() cannot handle the format launchdate is in. check what's in launchDate, then check what's in date. I think it goes wrong on that line, and you'll have to pass a date which new Date() can process.

Comment: the date was in milliseconds format when I parse it to Date. but when it hits the toLocaleDateString() line, it turns to invalid date. I believe the problem was lie on there.

Comment: ah, now I see the issue. You're trying to parse a date which has already been parsed, then converted to a string. You can just do the getUTC...() calls on date without having to convert it to a localedatestring. toLocaleDateString() is if you want to print it according to the locale of the user browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Date.parseExact(Your_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy').toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
```

or

```
Date.parseExact(Your_Date, 'MM/dd/yyyy').toString('dd/MM/yyyy');
```